# Can I send an HTTP request to an Alexa's Skill Endpoint in order to trigger a reprompt in Alexa?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

The scenario would be this.

I would start the skill with the corresponding command ("`Alexa, do whatever..`"), handle the subsequent `LaunchRequest` in the Skill Endpoint, and later (minutes later), Alexa would prompt the user with some question.

I'd like to know if I can trigger that late prompt (reprompt actually) in Alexa by sending a request to the corresponding Endpoint from a third Web Service. I guess I can handle HTTP request in the Endpoint (AWS Lambda function or whatever), but I don't know if I can trigger reactions in Alexa withouth it starting them first.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this would be allowed as it would break a fundamental privacy issue whereby interactions need to be initiated by the user and so be against the Alexa TOS.

If your "reprompt" doesn't actually require some 3rd party trigger e.g if you don't what to run something in response to a code event, then you could look at the reminders API.

You do need to request their permission initially to do this, so it would potentially change your flow somewhat, but then you could prompt them to re-engage with your skill this way.